# Spring REST api OAuth2 validating token from external authorization server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement my REST api which is the resource server used by mobile applications in my OAuth2 flow. I have an external authorization server made by someone else. Currently I have implemented getting the access token in the mobile application(Client in the OAuth2 flow I presume?) and now when I am making calls from the client to the resource server(REST api) I need the resource server to validate the token from the authorization server, before completing the request for the client. I have tried to look up various Spring-security-OAuth2 tutorials and I have managed to proceed a bit. Heres what i've currently came up with:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenService = new RemoteTokenServices();
        tokenService.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(
          end_point_url);
        return tokenService;
    }

}
```

Currently the authorization server `end_point_url` returns only `http 200` when its given a valid token in the request headers as `Authorization: Bearer VALID_TOKEN`. Right now my paths in the REST api are "secured" but all it takes is to pass header `Authorization: Bearer` and no token at all or any token when making requests to my REST api and it counts it as authenticated. I clearly have missed or not understood something. I think it is not validating the token at all from the authorization server or..? I don't honestly know.. Any ideas for what I need to do?

**UPDATE:**

As i've commented below, I have been following my external authorization servers logs aswell as my spring rest application logs. I have found out that with this configuration that i have presented here, the spring application is not extracting/using the authorization token that comes from the client(the mobile app) as `Authorization: Bearer VALID_TOKEN` but instead it makes the call to the authorization server with headers like `Authorization: Basic SOME_RANDOM_TOKEN`. Why is it ignoring and not using the token with the `Bearer` tag from the mobile app(client)?

Comment: you have missed several things. I recommend you read more about spring security works in their reference guide.
Also this tutorial can give you more information.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Comment: I've been reading that tutorial and i just dont understand the part i exactly need. Basically i could implement my own version of validating the token from the external authentication server by parsing the token from the header and making the call to the authorization server with the token included and throw exception if the response is not 200. But is there a correct way to do this "automagically" using the spring-security-oauth2 features?

Comment: well it depends, if you are just using token based authentication (not jwt) you can define in your application.properties where the authentication server is https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2 another tip for you is to define logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG in your application.properties and you can se exactly what it is spring security is doing in the logs.

Comment: I have been following my authorization server logs aswell as my spring application logs now. I noticed that the spring makes the authorization request to the authorization server, but it is not using the headers correctly now. It puts something like `Authorization: basic $some_random_token` when it should take the access token from the clients request(the mobile app) that has headers set as `Authorization: Bearer $Valid_access_token`. But for some reason it is not extracting it and using it from the mobile app(client)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so i've found a way to do exactly what I needed. I am not entirely sure that this is the correct way but it does EXACTLY what I wanted. So basically instead of using the `RemoteTokenServices` I used `UserInfoTokenServices` like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}

@Primary
@Bean
public UserInfoTokenServices tokenService() {
    final UserInfoTokenServices tokenService = new UserInfoTokenServices(USER_INFO_ENDPOINT, "");
    return tokenService;
}
```

By replacing my previous configurations with the example above my API now makes the request to my authorization server on EVERY request to the API to fetch the user info with the given access token. If it receives the user info we are gucci and otherwise we are unauthorized. Hope this helps someone!